# Data loss after repair

Tags: cassandra

Our repair jobs failed for a long period (> 14 days).
Today i manually started an repair job with `nodetool repair -pr`. Afterwards it looks like we lost some data from a table.

Question:
Is it theoretically possible to lose data after a repair job?
If yes what can be done to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not lose data with repair. If anything, you could gain back records that were deleted (resurrected zombie records).

One scenario where data might appear to be "lost" is if you have a missing tombstone cell copied from an alternate node during repair. That would be a correct value, not a lost value. If your client CL was something small, say, 1, and you're on the node with the data (but missing the tombstone), you might think that all-of-the-sudden you lost the cell, but again, that's the correct value.

Another scenario where things might appear to be "lost" is if the nodes time/clocks ever got out of sync and on your cluster where certain cells have incorrect time/date values causing things to get potentially messed up when repair tries to sync things up.

That's all I can think of off the top of my head.

-Jim

Comment: This is what I thought as well, but there seems to be an issue. I see audit logs of data added and miss logs about deletion. Can data be lost if a repair job is canceled and restarted?

Comment: Repair, or cassandra for that matter, only adds records (tombstones, values, etc). Doesn't modify anything that's already been done. Compactions can fire and possibly clean up expired cells, but again, that's what it's suppose to do.

Comment: Do you have a Time to Live (TTL) policy defined for that value? that could explain the missing record

Comment: I could resolve the issue, this had nothing to do with cassandra - the error was on application side.